# Azure Function App: compile code in EXE

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

the run.csx displays the code in Azure Function App. could we hide the code or compile in EXE so that the code is not seen on screen?

Comment: yes, but whats the point?

Comment: If you don't want someone to access the source code for .csx through the Azure Portal then use RBAC to control their access to the Azure Function app

Answer (score 4):

We support the deployment of **precompiled functions** (documentation [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Precompiled-functions)) allowing you to use precompiled assemblies rather than source code for your functions.